# C# Корректный вывод сообщения независимо от интерфейса вывода информации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь писать логику приложения, используя MVC.

Как корректно выдать сообщение, чтобы интерфейс правильно смог его получить и вывести пользователю?"

Логика такова, что если отчёт уже существует, выдать сообщение, что далее идёт его перезапись.

```
private void WriteReportDown(User user, DateTime date, int hours, string done, string path)
{
    if (!IsReportWritten(path, user, date))
    {
        try
        {
            WritingReportProcess(user, date, hours, done, path); // процесс записи отчёта
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Упс... непредвиденная ситуация!" +
                Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO : вывод сообщения
    }
}
```

Comment: Отдайте как JSON браузеру. Далее фронт (JS) пусть сам решает, как его показать. Можно WebSocket, можно AJAX, простор для творчества огромен.